# Can't build the MySQL drivers (Qt)

Tags: mysql, qt

I'm trying to build the MySQL drivers for Qt. I've downloaded and installed the MySQL Server files and I also got the Qt source files. After that i've tried to build the MySQL plugin, by opening the MySQL pro file (located at Qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql) and I've add path to the MySQL Server files (include and lib). When I now try to build it, I get the error "cannot open file 'mysql.lib'". So I checked if there is a mysql.lib file in the MySQL Server lib path and there wasnt, so I downloaded the C++ MySQL connector, but it doesnt contain a mysql.lib file either. So I need help, I'm not sure if I'm doing it right and if so, where can I get the mysql.lib file?

Thanks for all the help

Greets
Steven

Comment: Are you sure you dont mean libmysql.lib?

Comment: Show us the build output.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. That's why I'm so confused. Here's also a screenshot: https://gyazo.com/3f35d93e58585fbbe78cfb8fa300148c
Thanks for the response.

Comment: The Screenshot shows the build output.